# CloudBuild jobs not executed in parallel

Tags: google-cloud-build

I am learning CloudBuild and understand that I can use `waitFor` to influence the order in which my build runs. `job1` includes some sleep time to simulate a long running job. `job2` just echos something. `done` waits for `job1` & `job2`. So I created a test build like this: I have a `package.json`

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "job1": "echo \"[job1] Starting\" && sleep 5 && echo \"[job1] ...\" && sleep 2 && echo \"[job1] Done\" && exit 0",
    "job2": "echo \"[job2] Hello from NPM\" && exit 0",
    "done": "echo \"DONE DONE DONE!\" && exit 0"
  },
}
```

Job 1 simulates a long running job, where I was hopping job 2 will execute in parallel. But seems like the output shows its not. Does CloudBuild run 1 step at a time only?

`cloudbuild.yaml`

```
steps:
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm'
  args: ['run', 'job1']
  id: 'job1'
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm'
  args: ['run', 'job2']
  id: 'job2'
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm'
  args: ['run', 'done']
  waitFor: ['job1', 'job2']
```

**Output**

```
Operation completed over 1 objects/634.0 B.                                      
BUILD
Starting Step #0 - "job1"
Step #0 - "job1": Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm
Step #0 - "job1": 
Step #0 - "job1": > learn-gcp@1.0.0 job1 /workspace
Step #0 - "job1": > echo "[job1] Starting" && sleep 5 && echo "[job1] ..." && sleep 2 && echo "[job1] Done" && exit 0
Step #0 - "job1": 
Step #0 - "job1": [job1] Starting
Step #0 - "job1": [job1] ...
Step #0 - "job1": [job1] Done
Finished Step #0 - "job1"
Starting Step #1 - "job2"
Step #1 - "job2": Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm
Step #1 - "job2": 
Step #1 - "job2": > learn-gcp@1.0.0 job2 /workspace
Step #1 - "job2": > echo "[job2] Hello from NPM" && exit 0
Step #1 - "job2": 
Step #1 - "job2": [job2] Hello from NPM
Finished Step #1 - "job2"
Starting Step #2
Step #2: Already have image (with digest): gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm
Step #2: 
Step #2: > learn-gcp@1.0.0 done /workspace
Step #2: > echo "DONE DONE DONE!" && exit 0
Step #2: 
Step #2: DONE DONE DONE!
Finished Step #2
PUSH
DONE
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you wanted the `job2` to be executed concurrently with `job1` you should have added the line

`waitFor: ['-']` in your cloudbuild.yaml, immediatly after job2. As it is stated in the [official documentation](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/configuring-builds/configure-build-step-order):

> If no values are provided for waitFor, the build step waits for all prior build steps in the build request to complete successfully before running.
>
> To run a build step immediately at build time, use - in the waitFor
>   field.
>
> The order of the build steps in the steps field relates to the order
>   in which the steps are executed. Steps will run serially or
>   concurrently based on the dependencies defined in their waitFor
>   fields.

In the documentation is, also an [**example**](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/configuring-builds/configure-build-step-order#examples) on how to run two jobs in parallel.

In case you want job2 to run allong with job1 you should have something like this:

```
steps:

- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm'
  args: ['run', 'job1']
  id: 'job1'
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm'
  args: ['run', 'job2']
  id: 'job2'
  waitFor: ['-']  # The '-' indicates that this step begins immediately.
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/npm'
  args: ['run', 'done']
  waitFor: ['job1', 'job2']
```

Also note that the [maximum number of concurent builds](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/quotas) you can use is ten.